# Circular Dependency Error with SQLAlchemy using autoload for table creation

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am attempting to use the script found [here](http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2009/apr/27/copying-databases-across-platforms-sqlalchemy/).

I am connecting to an MS SQL database and attempting to copy it into a MySQL database. When the script gets to this line:

```
table.metadata.create_all(dengine)
```

I get the error of:

> sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError

I reasearched this error and found that it occurs when using the `autoload=True` when creating a table. The solution though doesn't help me. The solution for this is to not use `autoload=True` and to make use of the `use_alter=True` flag when defining the foreign key, but I'm not defining the tables manually, so I can't set that flag.

Any help on how to correct this issue, or on a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate through all constraints and set use_alter on them:

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import ForeignKeyConstraint

for table in metadata.tables.values():
   for constraint in table.constraints:
     if isinstance(constraint, ForeignKeyConstraint):
         constraint.use_alter = True
```

Or similarly, iterate through them and specify them as `AddConstraint` operations, bound to after the whole metadata creates:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.schema import AddConstraint

for table in metadata.tables.values():
    for constraint in table.constraints:
        event.listen(
           metadata,
          "after_create",
         AddConstraint(constraint)
        )
```

see [Controlling DDL Sequences](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/schema.html#controlling-ddl-sequences)